# I want to convert Column data into rows in excel. I have data like this

Tags: excel

in one column i have data

```
1

2

3

1

2

1

5

6
```

After 1  want to add new row and add the column data into rows
i want the out as

```
1 2 3
1 2 
1 5  6
```

Comment: Your output is not clear. You mean you want to transpose all? transpose before each 1 value? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to print my output like 1 2 3  in one row then in 2nd row my output will be  1 2 and then in 3rd row my ouptput will be 1 5 6

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like this:

[image: If you have data like this]

Just copy the data:

[image: Reference Image 2]

Then click on the Paste above and then select Paste Transpose:

[image: Check the image for your reference]

Finally, your output data looks like what you are looking for:

[image: Finally your result looks like that]

Comment: That doesn't meet the requirements of what they want, it just puts them all in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need VBA for this. You can use this code on a module, make sure the active sheet is the one with the values to transpose and then execute it:

[image]

```
Sub custom_transpose()
Dim i As Long
Dim MyValues As Variant
Dim InitialRow As Long
Dim ThisColumn As Long
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MyValues = Range("A1:A" & LR).Value

InitialRow = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(MyValues) Step 1
    If MyValues(i, 1) = 1 Then
        'because it's a one, we start a new row at column 2 (Column B)
        InitialRow = InitialRow + 1
        ThisColumn = 2
        Cells(InitialRow, ThisColumn).Value = 1
    Else
        'we keep same row but increase column number
        ThisColumn = ThisColumn + 1
        Cells(InitialRow, ThisColumn).Value = MyValues(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

Erase MyValues 'clear array
End Sub
```